# nodemailer is giving errors in Nextjs app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nodemailer

i have built a simple mailing app using nextjs and nodemailer, while watching a  [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JgcDZl8eXTg) And i did exaclty everything in the tutorial, but i am getting errors i have no idea how to troubleshoot. below is my code, kindly help and advise on how i sholud go about these errors

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import classes from './email.module.css'

const Email = () => {

    const [text, setText] = useState('')
    const handleClick = () => {
        const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')

        const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'hidden',
            port: 465,
            secure: true,
            auth: {
                user: 'hidden',
                pass: '********',
            },                      
        })

        const options = {
            from: 'hidden',
            to: 'hidden',
            subject: 'my test email',
            text: text
        }

        transport.sendMail(options, (err, info) => {
            if(err) {
                console.log('Error: ',err)
            }
            console.log('message sent: ', info.response)
        })
    }

  return (
    <div className={classes.cont}>
      <textarea value={text} onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)} className={classes.text}/>
      <button onClick={handleClick} className={classes.but}>send Email</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Email;
```

and below is my client console errors

```
next-dev.js?3515:32 ./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/dkim/index.js:10:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/mailer/index.js
./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/nodemailer.js
./comp/Email.js
./pages/index.js

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
window.console.error @ next-dev.js?3515:32
handleErrors @ hot-dev-client.js?1600:117
processMessage @ hot-dev-client.js?1600:167
eval @ hot-dev-client.js?1600:29
eval @ websocket.js?a9be:58
handleMessage @ websocket.js?a9be:57
next-dev.js?3515:32 ./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/mailer/index.js:14:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'dns'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/nodemailer.js
./comp/Email.js
./pages/index.js

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
window.console.error @ next-dev.js?3515:32
handleErrors @ hot-dev-client.js?1600:117
processMessage @ hot-dev-client.js?1600:167
eval @ hot-dev-client.js?1600:29
eval @ websocket.js?a9be:58
handleMessage @ websocket.js?a9be:57
next-dev.js?3515:32 ./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/mime-node/index.js:7:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/mail-composer/index.js
./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/mailer/index.js
./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/nodemailer.js
./comp/Email.js
./pages/index.js

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
window.console.error @ next-dev.js?3515:32
handleErrors @ hot-dev-client.js?1600:117
processMessage @ hot-dev-client.js?1600:167
eval @ hot-dev-client.js?1600:29
eval @ websocket.js?a9be:58
handleMessage @ websocket.js?a9be:57
next-dev.js?3515:32 ./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/sendmail-transport/index.js:3:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'child_process'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/nodemailer.js
./comp/Email.js
./pages/index.js

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
window.console.error @ next-dev.js?3515:32
handleErrors @ hot-dev-client.js?1600:117
processMessage @ hot-dev-client.js?1600:167
eval @ hot-dev-client.js?1600:29
eval @ websocket.js?a9be:58
handleMessage @ websocket.js?a9be:57
next-dev.js?3515:32 ./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/shared/index.js:7:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/nodemailer.js
./comp/Email.js
./pages/index.js

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
window.console.error @ next-dev.js?3515:32
handleErrors @ hot-dev-client.js?1600:117
processMessage @ hot-dev-client.js?1600:167
eval @ hot-dev-client.js?1600:29
eval @ websocket.js?a9be:58
handleMessage @ websocket.js?a9be:57
next-dev.js?3515:32 ./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/shared/index.js:9:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'dns'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/nodemailer.js
./comp/Email.js
./pages/index.js

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
window.console.error @ next-dev.js?3515:32
handleErrors @ hot-dev-client.js?1600:117
processMessage @ hot-dev-client.js?1600:167
eval @ hot-dev-client.js?1600:29
eval @ websocket.js?a9be:58
handleMessage @ websocket.js?a9be:57
next-dev.js?3515:32 ./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/http-proxy-client.js:8:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'tls'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/mailer/index.js
./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/nodemailer.js
./comp/Email.js
./pages/index.js

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
window.console.error @ next-dev.js?3515:32
handleErrors @ hot-dev-client.js?1600:117
processMessage @ hot-dev-client.js?1600:167
eval @ hot-dev-client.js?1600:29
eval @ websocket.js?a9be:58
handleMessage @ websocket.js?a9be:57
next-dev.js?3515:32 ./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:6:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'tls'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-pool/index.js
./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/nodemailer.js
./comp/Email.js
./pages/index.js

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nodemailer` is a Node.js library and cannot be used in the client side. That's why you see the error `Can't resolve 'fs'`.

What you may do instead is to create [an API route](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction)(which will be performed in the server side) and have the client app calls the API to perform the mailing task.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error too, even in app/[path]/route.js

To fix, I added the following to next.config.js

```
/** next.config.js - with Webpack v5.x */
module.exports = {

  ... other settings ... 

  webpack5: true,
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.fallback = {
      fs: false,
      net: false,
      dns: false,
      child_process: false,
      tls: false,
    };

    return config;
  },
};
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, @Rob Antoine! I want to warn you though, If you had the same error as the question and solved it with this, I think you may still have a problem in your code. The error happens when you try to use Node.js APIs in code that runs in the browser and your solution here basically tells Webpack to ignore it.
Also, for future answers, it can be really helpful to others if you can explain a bit about how you discovered the solution, how it works, or add links to relevant docs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).